# Recycler menu not aligning correctly

Tags: android

**RecyclerLayout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF00FF">  

   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/Recyclergrid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/app_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/Boxlayout" />
<LinearLayout >
```

**CardLayout.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:foreground="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/root">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/CardLayout"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/TextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/idIVcourseIV"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:minLines="2"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"  
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" 
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The java code i'm using is

```
Rcv= findViewById(R.id.Recyclergrid ); 
CardArray= new ArrayList<>();  
CardArray.add(new DataModel("Text" ,"Title"));
RecyclerAdapter RcvAdapter= new RecyclerAdapter(this, CardArray)
Rcv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));
Rcv.setAdapter(RcvAdapter);
```

The result im getting is this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/utWhA.jpg

I have tried adding gravity="center" in recycleview it still didnt work 
i did a workaround by adding padding to card view and centering recycler view is there any correct way to fix this

Answer (score 0):

First of All, Don't Use fix margins.

Use android:gravity = "center" in Your RecyclerView's Main Layout.

Or Get Proper Help. Here, you can use Grid layout to Show your data in app with Proper Margin.

follow this and set in app.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout

Comment: Grid layout is obsolete. Even though is not deprecated, it's not recommended to use.